# Can someone explain the solution to this math puzzle to me.

Tags: logic, intuition, puzzle

I am trying to solve [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/prison-cells-after-n-days/) leetcode problem. Basically there are 8 cells in a row. On a given day if a cell's two adjacent neighbor cells are both empty or both occupied then this cell gets a prisoner the next day. Otherwise, this cell becomes vacant the next day.

For the cells on the edge we assume they don't have a neighbor, so they will always become vacant eventually. Now the question is to predict the state of these 8 cells after N days. Where N will be given as an input. An initial state of the cells will also be given as input. By state they mean that we should output which of these 8 cells is occupied or vacant on a given day.

Apparently the intuition for the solution is that the state of these cells repeat itself after X number of days. Like for example if 1 represents occupied and 0 represents vacant. Then the state of these 8 cells could be something like this for example.
0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1.
This pattern apparently repeats itself after every X days. Using that we can quickly say what the state of these cells would be after N days. Rather than calculating the state of the cells on each day.

I don't understand why this state would repeat itself. None of the solutions give a proof for this. I don't even understand which branch of mathematics is concerned with solving problems like this. Can someone explain this solution to me.

Comment: There are a finite number of 8-cell states ($2^8$). Because the next state is completely determined by the current state, you will eventually enter a loop (although there may be some number of days at the beginning that are not part of the loop).

Comment: Ahh! Now I understand it. I don't get the second thing you said though. Why are the few cells at the beginning not part of the loop?

Comment: You might have something like $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 4 \to 5 \to 3 \to 4 \to 5 \to 3 \to \cdots$.

Comment: AHHHHH! Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't have the IQ for maths lol.